# Execute permission denied for perl script

Tags: perl, unix, ksh, anthill

I call a perl script from shell script.Since both unix shell script and perl script are created by me, i was able to execute it successfully.But when i deploy the code using anthillpro, permission of the files changed to 644. Hence when others execute this shell script, they are able to run unix script but following error is received while calling perl script.

```
0403-006 Execute permission denied.
```

Following code is used to invoke my perl script from unix shell script:

```
/usr/bin/perl /home/script/conversion.pl $layout_file $format_file $conv_file $base_filenm $COREPATH
```

First line of my perl script has following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Can anyone provide a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Give your perl script world read permission (`chmod u+r /home/script/conversion.pl`) and add execute permission for all directories on the path (`chmod u+x /home /home/script`).

Comment: I get the same error even after using these commands in my shell scripts. I will deploying these files in test and prod region, where we can not change execute permission of a directory.

Comment: Try /usr/bin/perl --version

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from the command `ls -l /home/script/conversion`.

Comment: To add to @Dave Cross' comment, you might want to check: `/bin/ls -ld /usr/bin/perl /home/script/conversion.pl /usr/bin /home/script /usr /home /` just for yuks.

Comment: Try to write the following in the step -
echo "Running perl"

pwd
ls -ltra

/home/script/conversion.pl $layout_file $format_file $conv_file $base_filenm $COREPATH


ls -ltra /home/script/
ls -ltra /usr/bin/perl

echo "DONE"